# How to show ProgressBar in centre of screen regardless layout types

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, layout, android-progressbar

I wonder if there is any way to show a `ProgressBar` at the middle of the screen programatically regardless the type of layout of the current Activity like a toast can be shown like,

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Sample toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: There is a difference Toast draws on Window its not part of your Layout . If `ProgressBar` is part of a layout then you need to set Rules to make it center . It you want to show it Overlay then you can use a `Dialog` which will automatically show in center ,,

Comment: One of the option will be to show progressbar in a dialog

Comment: But ProgessDialog is deprecated in latest Androids @ADM

Comment: @ManoharReddy how can we do that? It would be helpful if describe your idea in answer with sample code. Thanks..

Comment: I didn't said anything about progress dialog .. I said use a dialog .

Comment: @ADM sorry for misunderstanding but how can we show progress with a dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ADM and Reddy for guidance. Finally I was able to show a progressBar using dialog,

```
var loadingDialog: Dialog? = null

fun showLoadingDialog() {

    loadingDialog = Dialog(this)

    loadingDialog?.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    loadingDialog?.setCancelable(true)

    val relativeLayout = RelativeLayout(this)
    relativeLayout.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)

    val progressBar = ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge)
    val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150)
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)

    relativeLayout.addView(progressBar, params)

    loadingDialog?.window?.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayout.layoutParams)
        loadingDialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        loadingDialog?.show()
}

fun hideLoadingDialog(){

    loadingDialog?.hide()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use , I take app icon and rotate it in middle of the screen to show as progress , it looks better than just showing progress bar . If you still want progressbar just replace `ImageView` with `ProgressBar`

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.Window
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView

class MyProgressDialog : Dialog {
    private var dialog: Dialog? = null
    var imageView: ImageView? = null
        internal set
    internal var textView: TextView? = null


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, themeResId: Int) : super(context, themeResId) {
        init(context)
    }

    protected constructor(context: Context, cancelable: Boolean, cancelListener: DialogInterface.OnCancelListener?) : super(context, cancelable, cancelListener) {
        init(context)
    }


    fun init(context: Context) {

        dialog = this

        dialog!!.window!!.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog!!.setCancelable(false)


        val relativeLayout = RelativeLayout(context)
        val layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        relativeLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams


        val layoutParams_for_linear = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        layoutParams_for_linear.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)
        val linearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
        linearLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams_for_linear
        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout)


        val layoutParams_Linear = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        layoutParams_Linear.gravity = Gravity.CENTER


        imageView = ImageView(context)
        imageView!!.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        imageView!!.layoutParams = layoutParams_Linear

        linearLayout.addView(imageView)

        textView = TextView(context)
        textView!!.layoutParams = layoutParams_for_linear
        textView!!.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        textView!!.textSize = 18f
        linearLayout.addView(textView)


        val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f)
        animation.duration = 2500
        animation.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        animation.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        animation.start()


        dialog!!.window!!.setContentView(relativeLayout, layoutParams)
        dialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT))


    }


    fun setProgressMessage(message: String): Dialog {

        if (textView != null)
            textView!!.text = message

        return this
    }

    fun setProgressMessageSize(size: Int): Dialog {

        if (textView != null)
            textView!!.textSize = size.toFloat()

        return this
    }

    fun setProgressMessageColour(colour: Int): Dialog {

        if (textView != null)
            textView!!.setTextColor(colour)

        return this
    }

    fun setIcon(resId: Int): Dialog {

        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView!!.setImageResource(resId)

        }

        return this
    }


}
```

To show and hide Progress I use these methods

```
private var dialog: Dialog? = null

fun showProgress(context: Context?): Dialog? {
    if (context is Activity && (dialog == null || !dialog!!.isShowing)) {
        try {
            dialog = MyProgressDialog(context)
            dialog?.show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return dialog
}

fun dismissProgress() {
    try {
        if (dialog != null && dialog!!.isShowing) {
            dialog?.dismiss()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    dialog = null
}
```

Comment: Its working for your `ImageView` but it does not work for `ProgressBar`. Could you please check and let me know if it also works for `ProgressBar`? I want to simply show a progress bar. No image, no text.

Comment: I have selected your answer. I have also modified your code without creating another class. Please refer to my other answer. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: The `showProgress` and `dismissProgress` methods I wrote will take care that only 1 instance of the dialog is created and shown at a time . I will also take care of exception which may be caused when dismissing dialog when activity is about to end .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void showProgressDialog(Context context) {
    if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    try {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (mDialog.getWindow() != null)
            mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        layoutParams.copyFrom(mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

        int dialogWindowWidth = Validator.DtP(200,context);
        int dialogWindowHeight = Validator.DtP(150,context);

        layoutParams.width = dialogWindowWidth;
        layoutParams.height = dialogWindowHeight;

        // Apply the newly created layout parameters to the alert dialog window
        mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // dialog.setMessage(Message);

}

public static void hideProgressDialog(Context context) {
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

}

 public static int DtP(float dp, Context context) {
        return (int) (dp * (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    }
```

Comment: `mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout)`. whats the content of the `progress_layout`. I want to show it programatically. I am required not to use any layout.

Answer (score 0):

As ProgressDialog is deprecated, You can use Dialog(which by default appears in center of the screen) for showing progressbar in center.

layout_loading_progress_bar.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="85dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/progress_text"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:textColor="@color/textYellow"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

LoadingProgressBar.java

```
public void showProgress(Context context, String message, boolean cancelable) {
    mDialog = new Dialog(context);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_loading_progress_bar);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    ProgressBar mProgressBar = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    TextView progressText = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
    progressText.setText(message);
    progressText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    mDialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(cancelable);
    mDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgress() {
    if (mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create the progressBar programatically?

Comment: Yes you can create it programatically also and add it in any layout.

Comment: could you please modify your answer for adding progress bar programmatically?